# What's this extra R-like character on my '4' key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, dell-xps

I recently got a Dell XPS 13, it comes with a standard US-Intl layout (well, as 'standard' as these laptop keyboards get, anyway), except there is an extra R-like character on the <kbd>4</kbd> key.

I've never seen this character, and I can't find anything about it (it's rather difficult to search for such a thing).

The keyboard in question:

[image: Dell XPS 13 keyboard]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the Indian [Rupee symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign), aka Unicode U+20B9

Comment: It certainly does; Thanks :-) I'm not sure why Dell chooses to include this symbol for Dutch customers though... :-/

Comment: Well you're sorted if you go to India :)

Answer (score 1):

It is the symbol of Rupee , which is the currency of India

Comment: Same answer as previous one but, **7** years later!